# Insert Multiple rows from loop query

Tags: php, loops, mysqli

I'm trying to get a list of customers from a table and then append data onto them each day. I can't figure out how to insert into the database multiple rows with the same name

I have 3 tables: Companies, jobs, reports. I'm doing a 2 loops to get the companies and jobs data from the tables into a form which is added to each day which will go into the repots table. I've tried doing it as an array and doing it in a while loop, foreach loop but each time hasn't worked. I'm going wrong somewhere i just dont know where

```php
 $companyquery = "SELECT * FROM companiestest WHERE (enabled != 'true') ORDER BY name";
    $companies = $mysqli->query($companyquery);
    while($company = $companies->fetch_assoc()) {
        $cid = htmlspecialchars($company['id']);
        $companyname = htmlspecialchars($company['name']);
        echo "<tr>";
        $jobquery = "SELECT * FROM jobstest WHERE (cid = " . $company['id'] . ") AND (enabled != 'true') ORDER BY jobname";
        $jobs = $mysqli->query($jobquery);
            while($job = $jobs->fetch_assoc()) {                
                $bid = htmlspecialchars($job['id']);
                $product = htmlspecialchars($job['product']);
                $server = htmlspecialchars($job['server']);
                $medium = htmlspecialchars($job['medium']);
                $jobname = htmlspecialchars($job['jobname']);
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='backupid' value='$bid''>";
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='companyname' value='$companyname''>";
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='companyid' value='$cid'>";
                echo "<td>$companyname - $cid</td>";
                echo "<td>$product</td>";
                echo "<td>$server</td>";
                echo "<td>$medium</td>";
                echo "<td>$jobname</td>";
                echo "<td><select name='result' required>
                    <option disabled selected value>Result</option>
                    <option value='success'>Successful</option>
                    <option value='warn'>Warning</option>
                    <option value='fail'>Fail</option>
                </select></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' name='ticket' placeholder='Ticket Number'></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
```

```php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $companyname = strip_tags(trim($_POST['companyname']));
        $date = strip_tags(trim($_POST['date']));
        $staffmember = strip_tags(trim($_POST['staff']));
        $result = strip_tags(trim($_POST['result']));
        $ticket = strip_tags(trim($_POST['ticket']));
        $companyid = strip_tags(trim($_POST['companyid']));
        $jobid = strip_tags(trim($_POST['jobid']));

        $array = array();
        array_push($array, $companyname, $date, $staffmember, $result, $ticket, $companyid, $jobid);

        //$array = "('$companyname', '$date', '$staffmember', '$result', '$ticket', '$companyid')";

        print_r($array);

        $query = "INSERT INTO reporttest (company, date, staff, result, ticketnum, cid, bid) VALUES ($companyname, $date, $staffmember, $result, $ticket, $companyid, $jobid)";
        //echo "$query";
}
```

Comment: String values must be quoted when inserting to the database, or use  [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: Are you sure that `enabled` is supposed to be the string `'true'`, and not a true/false value?

Comment: This is very early in developemnt so before doing the prepared and binds i need to get the syntax right first. I forgot about the quotes so will add thanks

Enabled is a binary value in the database so when a customer leaves the company we mark it as false in the database which removes them from listing on the page

Comment: I’d suggest using prepared statements and binding now, as it will eliminate a whole host of quoting headaches, like this one. If enabled is a Boolean, then you need to pass 1/0 instead of a string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is a foreach loop with a key increment which inserts each variable into its own array. Then a foreach on the array to bind and execute into the database. Still a lot of modification to do with the data and restricting columns in the queries but so far it seems to be working without an issue.

No doubt there's a better way to do it but nobody has suggested anything to help as yet

```php
    $companyquery = "SELECT * FROM companiestest WHERE (enabled != 'true') ORDER BY name";
    $companies = $mysqli->query($companyquery);
    while($company = $companies->fetch_assoc()) {
        $cid = htmlspecialchars($company['id']);
        $companyname = htmlspecialchars($company['name']);
        echo "<tr>";
        $backupjobquery = "SELECT * FROM backupjobstest WHERE (cid = " . $company['id'] . ") AND (enabled != 'true') ORDER BY jobname";
        $backupjobs = $mysqli->query($backupjobquery);
            foreach($backupjobs as $key => $backupjob){
                $key++;

                $bid = htmlspecialchars($backupjob['id']);
                $product = htmlspecialchars($backupjob['product']);
                $server = htmlspecialchars($backupjob['server']);
                $medium = htmlspecialchars($backupjob['medium']);
                $jobname = htmlspecialchars($backupjob['jobname']);
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='backupid[]' value='$bid'>";
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='companyid[]' value='$cid'>";
                echo "<td>$companyname - $cid</td>";
                echo "<td>$product</td>";
                echo "<td>$server</td>";
                echo "<td>$medium</td>";
                echo "<td>$jobname</td>";
                echo "<td><select name='result[]' required>
                    <option disabled selected value>Result</option>
                    <option value='Successful'>Successful</option>
                    <option value='Warning'>Warning</option>
                    <option value='Failure'>Failure</option>
                </select></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='number' name='ticketnum[]' placeholder='Ticket Number'></td>";
                echo "</tr>";

        }
    }
```

```php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $results = array();
        $ticketnums = array();
        $cids = array();
        $bids = array();
        $date = strip_tags(trim($_POST['date']));
        $staffmember = strip_tags(trim($_POST['staff']));

        foreach ($_POST['result'] as $key => $result) {
            array_push($results, $result);
        }
        foreach ($_POST['ticketnum'] as $key => $ticketnum) {
            array_push($ticketnums, $ticketnum);
        }
        foreach ($_POST['companyid'] as $key => $cid) {
            array_push($cids, $cid);
        }
        foreach ($_POST['backupid'] as $key => $bid) {
            array_push($bids, $bid);
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO reporttest (date, staff, result, ticketnum, cid, bid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        if ( !$stmt ) { die('prepare failed'); }
        $stmt->bind_param("sssiii", $date, $staffmember, $result, $ticketnum, $cid, $bid);
        foreach ($bids as $key => &$bid) {
            $result = $results[$key];
            $ticketnum = $ticketnums[$key];
            $cid = $cids[$key];
            $bid = $bids[$key];
            if ($stmt->execute()) { 
                echo "Successfully updated the report";
            } else {
                echo "Error updating";
            }
            $stmt->fetch();
            printf("Date: %s, Staff: %s, result: %s, Ticket: %s, cid: %s, bid: %s", $date, $staffmember, $result, $ticketnum, $cid, $bid);
            echo "<br>";
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
```